# Python loading class from another file

Tags: python

I have a python script `NeoprobeApp.py` which calls a fitting function in `Parameter.py`  `Parameter.py` is given below

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

class Parameter:
    def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def set(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def __call__(self):
            return self.value

def fit(function, parameters, y, x = None):
    def f(params):
        i = 0
        for p in parameters:
            p.set(params[i])
            i += 1
        return y - function(x)

    if x is None: x = arange(y.shape[0])
    p = [param() for param in parameters]
    optimize.leastsq(f, p)
```

I import the fit function successfully `from Parameter import fit`. However, when I try to initialise my parameters

```
# Define initial parameters of Gaussian fit
        mu = Parameter(0)
        sigma = Parameter(20)
        height = Parameter(1)

        #define Gaussian fit function
        def f(angles): return height() * exp(-((angles-mu())/sigma())**2)

        fit(f, [mu, sigma, height], n_col_cnts)
```

I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NeoprobeApp.py", line 228, in OnPlot
    mu = Parameter(0)
NameError: global name 'Parameter' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question deserves a down vote

Comment: Downvoted because this is entry level stuff that is handled in every python tutorial that deals with the `import` statement. The error should also be very clear - your script doesn't know anything named `Parameter`. Any good IDE (for example, vim + pyflakes) would have notified you of this error _before_ running the code. Also, you seem to understand that you need to import your `fit` function, why do you think the `Parameter` class is special and doesn't need to be imported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just import the `fit` function, but not the `Parameter` class.

Use

```
from Parameter import fit, Parameter
```

instead of just

```
from Parameter import fit
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `fit` and `Parameter` are just names to denote things in the `Parameter` module. These names could be bound to anything. In this case, `fit` is bound to a function and `Parameter` is bound to a class. The list of names accessible at any point in code is defined by the scope of the names. The `import` statement brings names from other scopes into your current scope.

BTW: In python, modules should be named lowercase. A "Module" is generally the contents of a python file, so you should really name the file `parameter.py` and then your import statement would be:

```
from parameter import fit, Parameter
```